# How to add frequency information to date index in ARIMA model

Tags: python, python-datetime, arima, forecast

Error message for the following code: **A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.**

```
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train_data, trend='c', order=(1,1,2))
fitted = model.fit(disp=False)
print(fitted.summary())
```

Previously, my data (historical stock prices) have been parsed using the following code

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%Y-%m-%d')
tsla = pd.read_csv('TSLA_5.csv',sep=',',index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser=dateparse).fillna(0)
tsla.head()
```

it seems that datetime doesn't inlcude frequency information so we need to add our own. What should I add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this with the `DataFrame.index.freq` property. E.g., for daily data you set `tsla.index.freq = "D"` or for weekly data `tsla.index.freq = "W"`

You can find the offsets here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects

But beware that this will only work if your data follows this frequency strictly. If you are missing a single day for example, this will not really work and you need to either impute your data or use a custom offset.