# What is incorrect in my ARIMA model script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

According to the project, I have to create ARIMA model script in order to forecast US GDP. Code is  still not working, even though I try to reinstall all the libraries and rewrite whole code it still does not work.

I already asked question here and I was told that my values were wrong. I rechecked them and they are correct, but the code still doesn't work And I always get the same error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s8DdF_jANqtq6EFlUKgOykv6bpQ_4deUx13LvDIRCrk/edit

Comment: Seems like a straightforward error message. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71647632/7750891

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but after quick look on your code, you're passing daterange of forecast, same as daterange of dates you get to fit model. You should create daterange like eg.:

```
forecast_index = pd.date_range(start=forecast_end, end=end_date + pd.Timedelta(days=30), freq=freq)
```